# Java hierarchy with enum

Tags: java

I have a list of categories and some of them have subcategories. I need to implement this hierarchy using enumeration.
I did this:

```
  public enum Type {
   Category1(1, new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>()),
   Category2(2, getSubcategory2()),
    Category3(3, getSubcategory3());

    private final int id;
   private final Map<Integer, String> subcategories;


    Type(int id, Map<Integer, String subcategories) {
    this.id = id;
    this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> getSubcategories() {
    return subcategories;
    }
    }
```

I want a more elegant solution because in this moment if I want to see if a category have subcategories I have to verify every time if subcategories.size() > 0.

Comment: More elegant solution to what, exactly? You could easily had a `hasSubcategories` method which just returns `!subcategories.isEmpty()` if that would help.

Comment: Just a note, you can't use primitives as generics, they won't compile.  You should use `new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>()` instead.

Comment: How exactly is this `enum` used?

Comment: My personal opinion is that Enums are "hacky" solutions in cases like this. If there is relation between the elements and you have to add some specific constructor including maps, I would refactor the code to use some additional data structure (like a tree for instance to represent the parent-child relation).

Comment: Are you sure you want the sub-categories to be of the same enum type as the parent categories? Perhaps each set of sub-categories should be its own enum.

Answer (score 4):

```
public enum Category {
    CATEGORY_1(null),
        CATEGORY_1_1(CATEGORY_1),
        CATEGORY_1_2(CATEGORY_1),

    CATEGORY_2(null),
        CATEGORY_2_1(CATEGORY_2),
            CATEGORY_2_1_1(CATEGORY_2_1),
            CATEGORY_2_1_2(CATEGORY_2_1);

    private final Category parent;
    private final List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Category> roChildren = Collections.unmodifiableList(children);

    private Category(Category parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.children.add(this);
        }
    }

    public Category getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public List<Category> getChildren() {
        return roChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding description , what was issue in OPs code and what changed, so that other people also get help.